# Want to configre custom authentication rest API and for Authorization in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-gateway

I am new to WSO2 and want to use my custom Authentication API and Authorization API with WSO2.

I read the documentation of the WSO2 and find he CustomAuthenticationAPI. But I Still have following questions

- How to call authentication API from CustomAuthenticationAPI handler.
- Will that authentication rest api run without api gateway.
- How authentication token will be use by wso2 api gateway for further call.

**Current scenario**

we are using custom authentication api and custom authorization api, which is developed in spring boot and once user authentication done then it will hit to authorization api for permission and share that permission to authentication API, and authentication api will convert in jwt token, and share to caller in header.

How can I manage this flow with wso2?

Answer (score 0):

> How to call authentication API from CustomAuthenticationAPI handler.

Please refer code sample [2] mentioned in blog [1]

> Will that authentication rest api run without api gateway.

yes, if the Authentication API is an external API it will run independent of the gateway

> How authentication token will be use by wso2 api gateway for further
>   call.

The custom handler will replace the default authentication handler and validate the access token.

[1]. http://chalithak.blogspot.com/2018/01/wso2-apim-custom-authentication-handler.html

[2]. https://github.com/chalitha1989/WSO2-Custom-Components/blob/master/custom-okta-authenticator/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/authorization/UserAuthorizationHandler.java#L78